# ClassNotFoundException: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN, but I have access to this class

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, classnotfoundexception, alpn

I have such code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("ALPN class: " + ALPN.class);
    HelloWorldClient client = new HelloWorldClient("localhost", 10009);
}
```

This gives such output:

```
ALPN class: class org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ALPN is not configured properly. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting for more information.
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:136)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:124)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:94)
    at btcduke.node.ln.HelloWorldClient.<init>(HelloWorldClient.java:35)
    at btcduke.node.ln.HelloWorldClient.main(HelloWorldClient.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at io.grpc.netty.JettyTlsUtil.isJettyAlpnConfigured(JettyTlsUtil.java:34)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:153)
    ... 5 more
```

HelloWorldClient uses grpc, and it looks grpc is trying to load ALPN class dynamically. Am I right? This class can't be find, so I have error message. But please take a look,that I have access to this class (I print this class in first line). Do anyone knows why it happens this way? I have no idea :/

I toretically solved this issue by adding VM argument "-Xbootclasspath/p:" to run configuration option, but I don't understand why I needed to do this and also I don't think this is elegant method.

Comment: Did you read the part in the error message that starts with "ALPN is not configured properly"?

Comment: Do you think that `org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN` is the proper name for that class?

Comment: Before any more guesses are being made: look at the error message of the ClassNotFoundException thrown by the forName method call. It shows the string of the name as given in that call. Slashes are wrong - you should have periods there to separate package names.

Answer (score 3):

Documented at https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.php#alpn-chapter

**For Java 8 up to 1.8.0_242 included.**

You MUST use the `alpn-boot` provider for your specific JVM, as it modifies OpenJDK classes to enable support for ALPN.

See ALPN to OpenJDK version list:
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#alpn-versions

This `alpn-boot-<ver>.jar` requires use of the `-Xbootclasspath/p:` option on the JVM command line.

You will also use the [`jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server-<ver>.jar`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server) on your normal Server classpath for your specific version of Jetty server.

**For Java 8 from 1.8.0_252 and later (including Java 9+).**

For Java 8 from 1.8.0_252 included and later, this provider uses the standard OpenJDK ALPN APIs introduced in Java 9 (see below) that have been backported to 1.8.0_252 and *does not require* the `-Xbootclasspath/p:` option on command line

For this operational mode, use the [`jetty-alpn-java-server-<ver>.jar`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-alpn-java-server) artifact on your server classpath.

Comment: That's not OP's problem, though.

Comment: That is exactly the problem the OP is having.  The class `org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN` isn't loaded the way you think it is.  It has a boot classpath dependency that is preventing it from being loaded normally.

Comment: The error message for the ClassNotFoundException lists the argument of Class.forName. I don't think that a class name has slashes as separators between package names. It may come from a configuration file, though.

Comment: Thanks.

I added VM argument "-Xbootclasspath/p:" to run configuration option. Issue is gone, but I don't understand why I needed to do this and also I don't think this is elegant method.

Maybe this is because for some reason, this class have to be loaded before load my main classes?

Comment: @CD the `-Xbootclasspath/p:` option loads classes even before the JVM's own classes.  This is done by the ALPN layer to modify the JVM SSL classes to add ALPN support. (The first time ALPN support existed in the JVM is Java 9)

Comment: Hi guys, Im running into same problem, may I know how did you add this VM variable? is it like this ?  java -Xmx8192m -Xms4096m -Xss1024m -Xbootclasspath/p:  -jar mayJar.jar   ?

Comment: @TamerSaleh see https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions

Comment: I am getting this error in Java11. I am not allowed to use `-Xbootclasspath/p:` as it's been removed - any thoughts?

Comment: since -Xbootclasspath/p removed from java 11 ,any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: @vanshu it's best to open new questions for specific questions like yourself - the answer above has the details for Java 9+.

Answer (score 1):

If you received an error message "ALPN is not configured properly" or "Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured", it most likely means that:

ALPN related [dependencies](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting) are either not present in the classpath
or that there is a classpath conflict
or that a wrong version is used due to dependency management.

Looking closely at the provided stacktrace, it reveals that you need to configure "ALPN" properly

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at 
io.grpc.netty.JettyTlsUtil.isJettyAlpnConfigured(JettyTlsUtil.java:34)
```